# How to set default side-bar for for mat-card in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

This is my mark up used to display the json data

```
          <mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let filteredScreen of 
                    filteredScreens"  let i = index  [ylbHigh]="color">

              <mat-card-header>
                 <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image" >
                    <img mat-card-image class="list-img" src=" 
                       {{filteredScreen?.img}}" >
                 </div>
                <mat-card-content class="names" 
                     [innerHTML]="filteredScreen.name | highlight: name"  
                       [ylbHighlight]="color">{{ 
                 filteredScreen?.name }}
               </mat-card-content>
             </mat-card-header>
    </mat-card>
```

Its working fine

[image]

How can i set default side-bar for every name,I mean for the first name the side-bar should come default on clicking the next name for that name side bar has to come.Something like this

[image]

all the examples which i have referred are used for a particular div,but how can i apply it for mat-card component which is displaying json data.how can i achieve this??

Comment: Do you want the right side default that left the first item? what the component you use it on the right side?

Comment: I am not having any idea of using side bar,The 2nd image is just an example for the sidebar.

Comment: Do you have no idea to create the template or to pass the data in the sidebar to the right section?